# How to process information in an image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to write a java program so that when I capture the image of any one face of a Rubik's Cube, it tells which color is present on which tile. I dont want to use any prewritten library/api. I want to write the code myself. I want to ask how I should go about....I mean the steps.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this it analyzing one pixel at the time

```
     img = ImageIO.read(new File("/mydir/pic.png"));
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
            if (rgb == Color.RED.getRGB()) {
               //Do stuff

            } else  if (rgb == Color.GREEN.getRGB()){
                //Do more stuff
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of face of the cube in the image is variable then its not an easy task. Otherwise you can just use @urag's code but instead of checking for all pixels just check only 6 pixels in a row with an offset of tile width starting from first center of 1st tile.

Comment: The green color on all cubes wont be the same. How to handle that situation? Also, the program may pick up colour not on the cube (some other object which has come in the image along with the cube) How to go about then?

Comment: For checking green color, instead of checking for exact green color you can look for a range of rgb values related to all types of green colors. And for your second question try capturing image of face of cube only otherwise I think you will need knowledge of computer vision and machine learning to find your cube from the image.